# hibernate spatial 5 - Postgis2.2 : Query issues

Tags: hibernate, geometry, hql, postgis, spatial

Just started with postgis and hibernate statial and I'm gettin some issues making queries.

Goal : **Get a museum from a (its) geometry type object**

In my DB I got this column:

```
name: geom  
type: geometry(Point,4326))
that contains something like: 0101000020E6100000004C8E1516D(...) 

for each museum
```

Then, I've a museum class with:

```
@Column(name = "geom", columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")
private Geometry           geometry;
```

And here's my query:

```
WKTReader fromText = new WKTReader();
        try {
            //LON and LAT are the museum's coordinates
            Geometry geom = fromText.read("POINT("+lon+" "+lat+")");
            Session hibernateSession = getCurrentSession();

            Museum result = hibernateSession
                    .createQuery("from Museum where geometry = :geometry")
                    .setParameter("geometry", geom).uniqueResult();
            return result;


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            (...)
        }
```

But when I try to execute it, I got this Error:

```
ERROR: operator is not unique: geometry = bytea
Indice : Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So I was thinking, maybe Geometry from hibernate and Geometry from Postgis aren't the same?
Any idea on how I could make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

First I'd to make sure I'd the postgis dialect on my .properties file.

Added this Setter to have same SRID

```
geom.setSRID(4326);
```

Then I changed my query to:

```
.createQuery("from Museum where equals(geometry, :geometry) = true")
```

And also changed my db class to:

```
@Column(name = "geom", columnDefinition = "Geometry")
```

Works perfectly now. This might help someone with the same problem...

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

I was able to store 'geometry' data in postgis table using hibernate.

my pom.xml

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hibernate Entity:

```
 @Entity
 public class XYZ {

  @EmbeddedId
  private Key id;
  @Column(columnDefinition = "Geometry")
  private Point startLoc;
  @Column(columnDefinition = "Geometry")
  private Point endLoc;
 }
```

DAOImpl:

```
    Point start = new GeometryFactory().createPoint(newCoordinate(151.203446, 
             -33.867347, 1550285443));
    start.setSRID(4283);
    Point end= new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(151.203446, 
    -33.867347, 1550285443));
    end.setSRID(4283);
    summary.setId(key);
    try {
        summary.setStartLoc( start);
        summary.setEndLoc( start);
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
    iSaferJourneySummaryDAO.save(summary);
  }
```

- An important point in application.properties:
  **spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect**

PostGIS Column type : geometry